# Read files from folder before start

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to get an array of file names from my project public/logos folder. I am using create-react-app template and as you guess, I can not use `const fs = require('fs')` in browser after project start.

So, is there any way to fill an array right after `npm start` command and getting file names array from folder or am I out of context?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const appRoot = require('app-root-path').path

const getNames = () => {
    fs.readdir(path.join(appRoot, "public", "logos"), (err, files) => {
        return files
    })
}
```

Comment: you cannot read files from the browser. you have to use a server to serve those file.

Comment: @ViranMalaka you mean, should I create an node api and start the project via this?

Comment: you should behave a server to be read file used express  browser cont be able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the Sathishkumar is correct, it's not the only way: having  an application server just for reading static images can be too much in many situations.

What you can do is to **handle this by change the webpack configuration** (this requires you [eject](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) first so be **really careful**).

From webpack you have all of the Nodejs features available but you must make those changes static for the webapp.

An idea:

- manually copy with [html-copy-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) every image in the `dist` folder
- read every image file in that folder from node and generate a list of image names
- put the list of images as a global variable in your bundle by using [webpack DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

Now you will be able to read images names from this new global.

**Note**: this will not be a dynamic read of resources in a folder. If add/remove images you will be forced to repeat the build process of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is out of context. Not possible in browser-based JS application. You can't access the file system using Javascript in the browser.

You can use a NodeJS(or any other language for the same) to create a REST API as you mentioned which will return the files list and then can consume it(APIs like fetch or package - axios) in the frontend. This is the preferred way of doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read the files from file system you need to start server, like express, and then read this files on the server by request from frontend or by the link you pasted in your browser address field.